# Robolectric test exception from starting activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, robolectric

I am getting consistently failing tests on an Activity that I am testing. I have a significant amount of other tests doing similar things with similar test/actual code and not getting any Exceptions. The exception is always deeply buried inside Google Android code, related to traversing the views... I have no idea what the problem is. The code works find in reality.

I am starting an Activity with Support Fragments by running:

```
Robolectric.buildActivity(PartnersActivity.class).create().start().resume().get();
```

with View:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="3"
              android:baselineAligned="false">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and Activity:

```
public class PartnersActivity extends ActivityBase implements
        PartnersFragment.PartnerShowable, PartnersFragment.PartnerEditable,
        PartnersFragment.PartnerFinishable, PartnersFragment.PartnerDeletable {
    @Inject
    TabletDetector tabletDetector;

    @InjectView(R.id.main_container)
    @Optional
    FrameLayout mainContainerFrameLayout;

    private boolean tablet;

    private Partner updatedPartner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Injector.inject(this);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_container);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        tablet = tabletDetector.isTablet(mainContainerFrameLayout);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, PartnersFragment.create(tablet))
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public void newPartner() {
        if(tablet) {
            replaceMainFragment(CreatePartnerFragment.create());
        } else {
            CreatePartnerActivity.start(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deletePartner() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PartnersFragment.create(tablet))
                .remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_container))
                .commit();
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void editPartner(Partner partner) {
        replaceMainFragment(EditPartnerFragment.create(partner));
    }

    @Override
    public void showPartner(Partner partner) {
        if(tablet) {
            replaceMainFragment(PartnerFragment.create(partner));
        } else {
            PartnerActivity.start(this, partner);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void finishPartner(Partner partner) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PartnersFragment.create(tablet))
                .replace(R.id.main_container, PartnerFragment.create(partner))
                .commit();
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private void replaceMainFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_container, fragment)
                .commit();
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Fragment fragmentById = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_container);
        if(fragmentById == null || !(fragmentById instanceof CreatePartnerFragment))
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.partners, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.action_create_partner) {
            newPartner();
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == ActivityUtils.RESULT_CODE_OK && requestCode == ActivityUtils.REQUEST_CODE_UPDATE) {
            updatedPartner = (Partner) data.getSerializableExtra("partner");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();

        if(updatedPartner == null) return;

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PartnerFragment.create(updatedPartner))
                .commit();
        updatedPartner = null;
    }
}
```

and getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler.handleMessage(Choreographer.java:664)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.routeMessage(ShadowHandler.java:125)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.access$100(ShadowHandler.java:25)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler$1.run(ShadowHandler.java:110)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler$PostedRunnable.run(Scheduler.java:162)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOneTask(Scheduler.java:107)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.advanceTo(Scheduler.java:92)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.advanceToLastPostedRunnable(Scheduler.java:68)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.unPause(Scheduler.java:25)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.unPause(ShadowLooper.java:228)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:267)
    at org.robolectric.util.ComponentController.invokeWhilePaused(ComponentController.java:75)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.start(ActivityController.java:134)
    at jp.co.freee.freee.activities.PartnersActivityTest.setUp(PartnersActivityTest.java:65)
    at jp.co.freee.freee.activities.PartnersActivityTest.newPartner_whenPhone_startsCreatePartnerActivity(PartnersActivityTest.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:250)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```